# How to send string to clipboard by wolframscript

Tags: bugs, front-end, scripting, clipboard

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and fixed in 11.1.**

---

This is my `"t.txt"` file

```
#!wolframscript
UsingFrontEnd[CopyToClipboard["Hello,I have your d."]]
```

When I run `wolframscript -f "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\t.txt"` in *Windows CMD*.
[image]

I get nothing even a error information and the clipboard have nothing either.How to do this?

Comment: Why use `wolframscript` instead of `MathKernel`?

Comment: @JasonB. Actually I don't know how to do it with `MathKernel`.Do you mind give a show for it?

Comment: have to run right now, but see this:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140132/how-to-run-multiple-scripts-in-a-row-from-command-line-using-the-same-kernel/140134#140134