# How to run multiple scripts in a row from command line using the same kernel?

Tags: command-line, scripting

Here is my shell script so far (I am using MacOSX):

```
#!/bin/sh
math="/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel"
$math -run "<<input" -script script1.wl script2.wl > output
```

The two scripts I want to run in a row are script1.wl and script2.wl. The above seems to only run script1.wl

Anything obvious I am missing ?

Comment: I've never used the `-script` option.  What happens if you simply use `$math -run "<<input;<<script1.wl;<< script2.wl" > output`?

Comment: If you want to run them with the same kernel, why don't you run them *from within Mathematica* (`Get`) instead of from within a shell script?

Comment: @Szabolcs - sometimes you just don't want to be burdened with a front end :-)

Comment: @JasonB. I am not talking about the front end.  I just don't think that it is a good idea to mix Mathematica will shell scripts.  I meant: write Mathematica code to read in the two "scripts", not shell code.

Comment: @JasonB. That's essentially the same what you said. Sorry. I didn't red carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any syntax on [this page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html) for using 2 files with the `-script` option (and as MB1965 points out, the help does say that only one script file can be used with the `-script` option). I do have some experience running WL files from the command line in *Mathematica* in batch mode, all of which I learned from Jens's page [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/Mathematica.html).

If I create a file called "script1.wl" with the contents

```
x1 = 3;
x2 = 4;
```

and another file in the same directory, "script2.wl", with

```
Print[x1 + x2];
Exit[]
```

and then run this command from the same directory

```
math -noprompt -run "<<script1.wl;<<script2.wl" > output
```

where I've set `math` up as an alias in my shell to the `MathKernel` application, then the `output` file has a single line

```
7
```

Comment: Similarly if you run `RunProcess[{$script, "-help"}, "StandardOutput"]` it specifies that only one file can be passed.